# SVN TortoiseProc.exe : command to export the result displayed in Showcompare:

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to automate our deployment process. 
Question :- Am using this command to get modified files between trunk and working folder.

TortoiseProc.exe /command:showcompare /url1:C:\SVN\branches\Working_folder/folder1 /revision1:HEAD /url2:C:\SVN\trunk\folder1 /revision2:HEAD

With this command i get some midified file.
Now i want to export this list of files to my local C:\temp by using some command.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseProc is User Interface tool; it doesn't print anything to stdout, so you cannot use this data.

Your only option is to use plain `svn diff` command with url to repositories and redirect your output to the file:

```
svn diff --summarize http://svn/branches/path_to_working_folder@HEAD http://svn/trunk/path_to_working_folder@HEAD > C:\temp\diff_results.txt
```

More about this command in here: http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html

Comment: Thank you for your response but svn diff is only able to save the name of modified files. What i wanted to do is copying/exporting the modified file from this list of file to specific folder eg C:/temp . Is there any way automate this ? I do see TortoiseProc.exe /command:export command but concatenation if showcompare and export is not working .

Comment: I want to copy modified list of files as if we copy from SVN gui to deployment migration folder.

Comment: or is there any batch command to copy svn file from the repo browser to local folder ? thanks